connecting two networks over vpn
I have two network, both with an internet connection. One linux station (Debian 12) per network are connected by vpn.
I have this scenario:
net 192.168.160.x --> 
  default gateway 192.168.160.4
  vpn server 192.168.160.13

net 192.168.165.x --> 
  default gateway 192.168.165.4
  vpn client 192.168.165.2

vpn net 192.168.163.x -->
  server 192.168.163.1
  client 192.168.163.2

on vpn server I have this routing table
[sudo] password di mirko: 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.160.4   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
192.168.160.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
192.168.163.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.163.2   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.165.0   192.168.163.2   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0

on every machine in the 160 network has this routing table
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.160.4   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp4s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.160.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp4s0
192.168.163.0   192.168.160.13  255.255.255.0   UG    100    0        0 enp4s0
192.168.165.0   192.168.160.13  255.255.255.0   UG    100    0        0 enp4s0

on the other side on vpn client I have
mmk@dadun:~$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.165.4   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp2s0
62.108.229.77   192.168.163.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
192.168.160.0   192.168.163.1   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.163.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.165.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0

while every machine on 165 network has this routing table
root@vetrata:/home/mmk# /sbin/route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.165.4   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.160.0   192.168.165.2   255.255.255.0   UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.163.0   192.168.165.2   255.255.255.0   UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.165.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0

obviously on the both side the vpn I've enabled ip forwarding
root@dadun:~# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
root@idea:/var/yp# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

but I've this problem:
from vpn-client (165.2) I'm able to connect to every machine on 160 network, but from vpn server (160.13) I'm not able to connect to any machine of 165 network
Why?

To have a client effectively serve as a "gateway" (effectively; TUN VPN is L3 only), you'll need to set up an iroute on the VPN server. (The gateway of the 192.168.165.0/24 route is bogus. iroute is the way to actually tell OpenVPN which client is the "gateway" for certain destinations. See the OpenVPN manual for further details.)

thanks Tom. Anyway I've the client-config-dir file with iroute 192.168.165.0/255.255.255.0

To have a client effectively serve as a "gateway" (effectively; TUN VPN is L3 only), you'll need to set up an iroute on the VPN server. (The gateway of the 192.168.165.0/24 route is bogus. iroute is the way to actually tell OpenVPN which client is the "gateway" for certain destinations.)
The syntax should be iroute 192.168.165.0 255.255.255.0 (space, not slash, between the destination and the netmask); also both the route and the iroute should be added on the server side (hence client-config-dir too). Also note that the file in the client config dir should have the same name as the client's X509 common name.

As far as I can see you have the following situation:
(Trying my best with ASCII graphics written on a phone). :-)
192.168.160.x/24 --- Server --- GW1 ---Internet --- GW2 --- Client --- 192.168.165.x/24

            eth0:  192.168.160.13              eth0: 192.168.165.2
            tun0:  192.168.163.1 -- VPN Net -- tun0: 192.168.163.2

In order to every host on 192.168.160.x be able to ping any host on 192.168.165.x then you will need to add a static route on GW1 in my graphic above saying something like:
192.168.165.0/24 via 192.168.160.13.
Similarly you will need to add static route on GW2 saying:
192.168.160.0/24 via 192.168.165.2
On top of that you do not tell what kind of vpn software you are using, so what additional you have to varies at this point.
OpenVPN has a directive called iroute that tells a subnet is available behind a specific VPN client.
Read up on iroute works with the client-config-directory.
Wireguard uses the AllowedIPs directive on seever side for same purpose.
StrongSwan (IPsec) has a different way, which I can't remember at the moment.
... and it goes without saying that ip forwarding has to be enabled on VPN server and VPN client and the firewall on server and client allows inbound traffic from the subnet on the other side of the VPN connection.

yes, i have those static route, on the server side is set by dhcp, on the client side is set by client-config-dire but i've wrote iroute 192.168.165.0/255.255.255.0
this configuration doesn't work

i've changed to iroute 192.168.165/24 but nothing is changed

@mkk It should be iroute 192.168.165.0 255.255.255.0 (space not slash); also both the route and the iroute should be added on the server side (hence client-config-dir too). Also note that the file in the client config dir should have the same name as the client's X509 common name

thanks tom! the slash was the problem! now all works! If you want to transform in answer I'll accept it!
